# Action Required: Drive API requires updates to your code before Sep 13, 2021

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

Recevied an email from Google with above title, and listing a few of my projects that are affected.
These projects run app script with simple code to get file or folder by id.

```
  var reportFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXX"); 
  var reportTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXX"); 
  var workReport = reportTemplate.makeCopy(reportFolder);
```

I am new to all this, would appriciate some advice if I need to update my code and if so how?
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what the issues is with your code.   We cant tell you what you need to update only you can decide what needs to be changed.